# How can I set PYTHONPATH in fish?

Tags: python, ubuntu, fish

The following works in bash:

```
~$ echo $PYTHONPATH
<nothing>
~$ export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/test/folder
~$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/path/to/test/folder
~$ python -m test_script
hello world
```

But not in fish:

```
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
Type help for instructions on how to use fish
~> echo $PYTHONPATH
<nothing>
~> set --universal PYTHONPATH /path/to/test/folder
~> echo $PYTHONPATH
/path/to/test/folder
~> python -m test_script
/usr/bin/python: No module named test_script
```

I've tried `set`, `set --global` and `set --universal`.

How can I set PYTHONPATH in fish? (If it matters, I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setting the variable is not sufficient, you must *export* it too (as you do in bash). Exporting means that subprocesses (like the Python call) will get the value too.

From the [fish documentation](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#set):

> -x or --export causes the specified environment variable to be exported to child processes

So a direct equivalent to the bash directive would be:

```
~> set --export PYTHONPATH /path/to/test/folder
```

You could add `--universal` or other arguments, but here the value is temporary, which matches the original bash example.

(Found answer via [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624512/setting-exports-in-fish-shell).)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to make the change permanent then you can  add 
 the following line

`set -xg PYTHONPATH /path/to/test/folder $PYTHONPATH`

to the bottom of `~/.fish/config.fish`

Comment: The path for me was `~/.config/fish/config.fish`, but this still worked so thanks