# Append *multiple* paths to PYTHONPATH in fish

Tags: python, environment-variables, fish

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308310/how-can-i-set-pythonpath-in-fish) I read how to append to PYTHONPATH in fish, and that works fine for one string.

However, if I do this:

`set --export PYTHONPATH $PYTHONPATH path1 path2`

I get this:

```
>> import os
>> os.environ["PYTHONPATH"]
'path1\x1epath2'
```

Alternatively:

```
$ python -c "import os; print os.environ['PYTHONPATH']"
path1path2
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set multiple paths by colon-separating the paths in the environment variable. I don't use fish, but in ZSH for instance, I'd do:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/foo:/path/to/bar
$ python -c "import sys; print sys.path"
['', '/path/to/foo', '/path/to/bar', ...
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Tried `set --export PYTHONPATH $PYTHONPATH "path1;path2"` and got `"path1;path2"` as a single path. In fish, usually, you set multiple elements by space-seperating them.

Comment: yes, but fish doesn't necessarily *use* those environment variables. If python requires a colon-separated string, use `set -x PYTHONPATH "$PYTHONPATH:path1:path2"`

Comment: @Xiphias colon-separated, not semicolon. it will appear in `os.environ` as a single environment variable (it is just one, after all), but it will be added to `sys.path` (which is what we want anyway) as two items.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks, your comment should be the accepted answer here!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using fish 2.2.0 (or the just released 2.3.0) there are only three env vars that are automatically split and joined by colons: PATH, MANPATH, CDPATH. All other "path" list env vars are treated as single element arrays unless you explicitly set them to more than one value as in your example. However, if you do that when they are exported the values are separated by the ASCII RS (0x1E) character. You should handle PYTHONPATH just as you would in bash, zsh, etc.

The fish project has several issues open where we're discussing possible improvements to the handling of such variables. See

https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2090

https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1656

https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/436

Answer (score 0):

Fish is providing a new mechanism to deal with this issue in the upcoming 3.0 release.

Please see the following PR for more info: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/pull/5245